# Arranging a JSON string on the basis of UI

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a repeater grid which is populated on the basis of a JSON which is serialized into an object which a bind as the datasource to a repeater.

The user is allowed to arrange the elements of the grid as per will and I have to save in exactly that order.

The approach I am taking is to place the JSON string in a hidden field and manipulating it as the user arranges so that the JSON reflects the order in the UI.

Could not find any functions in jQuery to manipulate or sort the JSON.

Please advise on the functions or the approach which I should take.

Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) or [`grep()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Or native javascript [<kbd>array methods</kbd>](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/) like sort() on your JSON Array

It is always better to add your code and the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I have'nt coded as yet as not sure that this is the best approach., also how would I arrange the JSON according to the UI ?